# Making a buy/sell decision on a stock quote

Tags: python

I have been working with Python for about six months, mostly learning by doing. I have ten or twenty variables that I pass around to different functions. I had the idea to put them into a dictionary and just pass the dictionary around. I have researched stack overflow extensively but I can't find anything that says this is a good idea or not.

Python seems to have many things that you can do but should not. Below is a prototype of the program that I wrote to test the idea. It works as I want it to. I would appreciate comments from more experienced programmers about any aspect of the code, but especially regarding the dictionary as a parameter.

The program is receiving a stock quote on each iteration and making a buy/sell decision if this helps.

```
def makevd():
    # Variables are grouped into functions whose names describe actions or states.
    def wrtn():
        return abs(vd['chapcv'])> vd['trigger']
    def wrhn():
        return vd['holdem'] and vd['wrwn']()
    def wrwn():
        return vd['chapcv']* vd['nuii']> 0
    def wrcn():
        return vd['chapcv']* vd['nuii']> 0 and vd['chapmav']< 0
    def wrpn():
        return vd['chapcv']* vd['nuii']> 0 and vd['chapcv']> vd['trigger']* 3
    # Variable dictionary contains variables that are used in making the Buy/Sell decision.
    vd={
    'holdem':False,
    'i':0,
    'iterations':0,
    'trigger':0,
    'chapv':0,   # Future
    'chapvv':0,  # Future
    'chapmav':0,
    'chapcv':0,
    'nuii':0,
    'wrtn':wrtn, # chapc, trigger
    'wrhn':wrhn, # holdem ,chapc, nuii
    'wrwn':wrwn, # chapc, nuii
    'wrcn':wrcn, # chapc, nuii, chapmav
    'wrpn':wrpn, # chapc, nuii, trigger
    }
    return vd
        def snull(vd):
        vd.update({'msg':'Senario null. All default values.'})
        return vd
    def s1(vd): # OK
        vd['i']=6
        vd['msg']='Senario 1, Just return vd.'
        return vd
    def s2(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00001
        vd['msg']='Senario 2 wrtn() False, chapcv < trigger. Just continues looking for trigger price.'
        return vd
    def s3(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00016
        vd['holdem']= False
        vd['msg']='Senario 3, wrtn() True, wrhn False. Trades every iteration.'
        return vd
    def s4(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00016
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['nuii']= -3
        vd['msg']='Senario 4, wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() False. Trades every iteration.' 
        return vd
    def s5(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00016
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['nuii']= 3
        vd['chapmav']= 1
        vd['msg']='Senario 5, wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False, wrpn() False. Just continues does not trade.'
        return vd
    def s6(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00016
        vd['nuii']= 3
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['chapmav']= -1
        vd['msg']='Senario 6, wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() True,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn. Trades every iteration.'
        return vd
    def s7(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00050
        vd['nuii']= 3
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['chapmav']= vd['chapmav']- 1
        vd['msg']='Senario 7, wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() True. Trades on wrpn. Trades every iteration.'
        return vd
    def s8(vd): # OK 
        vd['chapcv']= 0.00016
        vd['nuii']= 3
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['chapmav']= vd['chapmav']-1
        vd['msg']='Senario 8, wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn descending.'
        return vd
    def s9(vd): # OK
        vd['chapcv']= vd['chapcv']+0.00017
        vd['nuii']= 3
        vd['holdem']= True
        vd['chapmav']= 1
        vd['msg']='Senario 9, wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrpn ascending.'
        return vd
    # assign values to variables to test alternate senarios
    # run senario for iterations 
    def dealanotherhand(vd):
        vd= s5(vd)
        x= vd['i']+ 1
        vd.update({'i':x})
        return vd

    def algo0(holdem, testmode, tf1, ibfilename): 
    iterations = 5
    trigger    = tf1
    vd= makevd()
    vd.update({'holdem': holdem, 'i':0, 'iterations':iterations,'trigger':trigger})
    while vd['i'] <= vd['iterations']:
        vd= dealanotherhand(vd)
        #===============================================================================================
        if not vd['wrtn']():                           # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR SIGNAL TO TRADE   
            continue                                       # LOOK FOR TRADE SIGNAL
        if vd['wrhn']() and vd['wrwn']():              # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
            if not vd['wrcn']() and not vd['wrpn']():  # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
                continue                                   # LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
        #===============================================================================================
        print('TRADE TRADE TRADE ','i ',vd['i'])     # EXECUTE AT MARKET
        print(vd['msg'])
    print(vd['msg'])
    return vd 

    # Calling Function
    vd= algo0(True, True, 0.00015, 'test')
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of this could be improved with OOP.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do (and I don't understand that by looking at the code) it's hard to say something. I think you have bigger problems than passing or not passing dict as an argument.

Comment: Fix your indentation, fix errors and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: @user1685095 I've tried to fix some of it, it was bug with SE's codeblock format I think.

Comment: But as he said, Thomas, can you provide an example of how it works?

Comment: Also, I've been trying to improve your code, and I've noticed this: CR is only for working, finished code. Some of your bits are marked `#FUTURE`, presumably to add later. You should probably update with a completed version, so people can actually tell what to fix.

Comment: The indentation looks wrong. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block. Furthermore, this question lacks sufficient explanation about what the code is designed to accomplish. Putting this question on hold as Unclear for those two reasons.

Comment: Furthermore, Code Review questions should be about your code (for stock evaluation) rather than a practice in general (passing dictionaries). Please retitle the question according to the site guidelines (see [ask]).

Comment: Riker, How this works? This is intended only as an example of passing parameters as a dictionary. The purpose of the program is to test variables and combinations of variables to see if they give the expected result. Your conversion to OOP is very helpful and is just what I need to start to understand how to use Class Structures. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I"m not sure what this code is supposed to do. However, this functions identically to your original code, but is a bit cleaner:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

check_in_dict = lambda item, dct, rtype: dct[item] if item in dct else rtype()

class VDict(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.msg = check_in_dict("msg", kwargs, str)
        self.holdem = check_in_dict("holdem", kwargs, bool)
        self.i = check_in_dict("i", kwargs, int)
        self.iterations = check_in_dict("iterations", kwargs, int)
        self.trigger = check_in_dict("trigger", kwargs, int)
        self.chapcv = check_in_dict("chapcv", kwargs, int)
        self.chapmav = check_in_dict("chapmav", kwargs, int)
        self.nuii = check_in_dict("nuii", kwargs, int)
        self.chapv = check_in_dict("chapv", kwargs, int)  # TBA
        self.chapv = check_in_dict("chapvv", kwargs, int) # TBA

    def wrtn(self):
        return abs(self.chapcv) > self.trigger

    def wrhn(self):
        return self.holdem and self.wrwn()

    def wrwn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0

    def wrcn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0 and self.chapmav < 0

    def wrpn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0 and self.chapcv > (self.trigger * 3)

class Scenario(object):
    def __init__(self, vdict):
        self.vdict = vdict

    def sNull(self):
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario null: all default values."

    def s1(self):
        self.vdict.i = 6
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 1: just return vd"

    def s2(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00001
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 2: wrtn() False, chapcv < trigger. Just continues looking for trigger price."

    def s3(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = False
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 3: wrtn True, wrhn False. Trades every iteration."

    def s4(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.nuii = -3
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 4: wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() False. Trades every iteration."

    def s5(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.chapmav = 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 5: wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False, wrpn() False. Just continues does not trade."

    def s6(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = -1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 6: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() True,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn. Trades every iteration."

    def s7(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00050
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = self.vdict.chapmav - 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 7: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() True. Trades on wrpn. Trades every iteration."

    def s8(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = self.vdict.chapmav - 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 8: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn descending."

    def s9(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = self.vdict.chapmav + 0.00017
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 9: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrpn ascending."


def deal_another_hand(vdict):
    scenario = Scenario(vdict)
    scenario.s5()
    vdict.i += 1
    return vdict

def algo0(hold, testmode, tf1, ibfilename): 
    vd = VDict(msg = "", holdem = hold, i = 0, iterations = 5, trigger = tf1)

    while vd.i <= vd.iterations:
        deal_another_hand(vd)

        #===============================================================================================
        if not vd.wrtn():                          # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR SIGNAL TO TRADE   
            continue                                       # LOOK FOR TRADE SIGNAL
        if vd.wrhn() and vd.wrwn():           # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
            if not vd.wrcn() and not vd.wrpn():  # OR TRADE OR LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
                continue                                   # LOOK FOR BETTER PRICE
        #===============================================================================================
        print("TRADE TRADE TRADE ","i ",vd.i)    # EXECUTE AT MARKET
        print(vd.msg)
    print(vd.msg)
    return vd 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    algo0(True, True, 0.00015, "test")
```

Let's break this down, and I'll explain the changes.

The very first thing I notice is the `makevd` function. This appears to construct a dictionary, with specific parameters. It turns out, python has a special kind of function for this: a `class`.

Classes are like variables, that have special functions and sub-variables attached for them. For example, your function creates and returns a `dict` with functions inside of it.  Here's `makevd` as a class:

```python
class VDict(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.msg = check_in_dict("msg", kwargs, str)
        self.holdem = check_in_dict("holdem", kwargs, bool)
        self.i = check_in_dict("i", kwargs, int)
        self.iterations = check_in_dict("iterations", kwargs, int)
        self.trigger = check_in_dict("trigger", kwargs, int)
        self.chapcv = check_in_dict("chapcv", kwargs, int)
        self.chapmav = check_in_dict("chapmav", kwargs, int)
        self.nuii = check_in_dict("nuii", kwargs, int)
        self.chapv = check_in_dict("chapv", kwargs, int)  # TBA
        self.chapv = check_in_dict("chapvv", kwargs, int) # TBA

    def wrtn(self):
        return abs(self.chapcv) > self.trigger

    def wrhn(self):
        return self.holdem and self.wrwn()

    def wrwn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0

    def wrcn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0 and self.chapmav < 0

    def wrpn(self):
        return (self.chapcv * self.nuii) > 0 and self.chapcv > (self.trigger * 3)
```

Now, instead of referencing things as `vd["i"]`, you reference them as `vd.i`. The only change is that you need to create a `VDict` object first, with something like `vd = VDict()`.

Also, in case you didn"t know: `kwargs` are optional **k**ey**w**ord **arg**ument**s**.  This allows you to create a `VDict` object with the subvariables, such as `trigger` or `chapcv` automatically built in.  To help with this, I also made a `check_in_dict` lambda function. You can read that yourself.

---

Next, instead of having 9 different scenario functions, I made that into a class. This `Scenario` class takes a `VDict` when it"s defined, by `scenario = Scenario( VDict() )`.

Here"s the class:

```python
class Scenario(object):
    def __init__(self, vdict):
        self.vdict = vdict

    def sNull(self):
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario null: all default values."

    def s1(self):
        self.vdict.i = 6
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 1: just return vd"

    def s2(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00001
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 2: wrtn() False, chapcv < trigger. Just continues looking for trigger price."

    def s3(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = False
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 3: wrtn True, wrhn False. Trades every iteration."

    def s4(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.nuii = -3
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 4: wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() False. Trades every iteration."

    def s5(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.chapmav = 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 5: wrtn() True, wrhn() True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False, wrpn() False. Just continues does not trade."

    def s6(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = -1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 6: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() True,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn. Trades every iteration."

    def s7(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00050
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = self.vdict.chapmav - 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 7: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() True. Trades on wrpn. Trades every iteration."

    def s8(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = 0.00016
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = self.vdict.chapmav - 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 8: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrcn descending."

    def s9(self):
        self.vdict.chapcv = self.vdict.chapmav + 0.00017
        self.vdict.nuii = 3
        self.vdict.holdem = True
        self.vdict.chapmav = 1
        self.vdict.msg = "Scenario 9: wrtn() True, wrhn(), True, wrwn() True, wrcn() False,  wrpn() False. Trades on wrpn ascending."
```

You start with `scenario = Scenario(VDict())`, and then you can refer to the subfunctions as `scenario.snull`, `scenario.s1`, etc.

---

Also, in the `dealanotherhand` function, there are two things here:

- First, python prefers `snake_case` for function names. (but `PascalCase` for classes) This should be named `deal_another_hand` by those rules.
- Second, you now have an unneeded `x` variable. (`x = vdict.i + 1; vdict.i = x`). You can now change this to `vdict.i += 1`.

Here"s the new function:

```python
def deal_another_hand(vdict):
    scenario = Scenario(vdict)
    scenario.s5()
    vdict.i += 1
    return vdict
```

(I've created the `Scenario` object within the function, but you can change that and make the function take it as a parameter. That"s dependent on what you"re doing next with this code.)

---

Lastly, I've added an `if __name__` statement to the end. This tells python to not execute what's inside of it, unless it's being run manually. For example, it would be executed if you're running the script via something like `./stocks.py`.

However, if you're going to import this into another project, it wouldn't execute the insides. This is so you can do something like `import stocks`, and then use the `VDict` or `Scenario` classes for another stock market bot.

That's it! The only other thing I changed was all the single quotes to double quotes (`'' -> ""`), and that's just personal preference. Pick a style and stick to it.

Notice I didn't change the contents of `algo0` at all, except for compatibility with the class changes (i.e. defining the class with the parameters instead of updating later, and then changing `vd['x']` to `vd.x`. It looks okay to me, and it doesn't look finished yet, so I can't really modify too much anyway.

Hope this helps!